# How to ignore missing keys in pandas while summing along columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains word embeddings. Words are column names. To get the final embedding of a sentence, I do this:

```
st = ['some','random','text']
a = df[st].sum(axis=1)
```

This works well when all the terms are present in the dataframe. However, it raises a keyerror when the column is not present in the dataframe. Currently, I am looping for each term and doing try except. I would like to avoid the loop and do the thing in one line. Is there an option provided by pandas for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `intersection`:

```
df[df.columns.intersection(st)].sum(axis=1)
```

This will only sum columns if they exist in `df`

Comment: The number of columns is fairly large (400000 columns). Will this be efficient?. Is there a better method? Should I go for df.loc?

Comment: I am looking for something like ignore missing columns. I am willing to change the underlying pandas library if necessary.

Comment: Yes, this will ignore missing columns. It is the most efficient I can think of, as it will only return columns that are BOTH in `st` and `df.columns`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the assignment with:

```
st = [w for w in ['some','random','text'] if w in df.columns]
```

to eliminate any words that are not present.